# how to eliminate empty resultsets in SPARQL?

Tags: resultset, sparql, jena

I am doing a project under Semantic Web.This is an example of RDF file i am using

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
> xmlns:foaf="http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1">
> <rdf:Description>
>     <foaf:name>aricent</foaf:name>
>    <foaf:url>www.placementhub.net</foaf:url>
>   </rdf:Description>
> </rdf:RDF>
> ```

if user enters "prepare for aricent" for searching the link,I coded in a way to take each value "prepare","for","aricent" and dynamically generate SPARQL query to find the related record.This is the SPARQL query

> String queryString ="PREFIX rdf:
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns# " +
>                       "PREFIX foaf: http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1 " +
>                       "SELECT ?name ?url WHERE { ?a foaf:name ?name   FILTER regex(?name,'"+         values[i]+"') ?a foaf:url ?url }";

where values[i] is now " prepare" in 1st loop,"for" in 2nd loop and "aricent" in 3rd loop.
In such a case if it is executed i will get as

```
--------------------------------------
| name       | url                   |
======================================
|            |                       |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
| name       | url                   |
======================================
|            |                       |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
| name       | url                   |
======================================
| "aricent" | "www.placementhub.net" |
--------------------------------------
```

So the resultset is empty(with no values) for "prepare" and "for" and result is got only for "aricent" as it is available in RDF.Can you please tel me how to eliminate(only the table that has value should be shown to the user) the empty resultsets obtained?i used JENA API's.Thank You

Comment: We'll need a bit more detail. What does your SPARQL query look like? Which tool/API are you using to execute the query and process the result? Also: what exactly do you mean with "the empty resultsets obtained"?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you mean by eliminate here, but you could do all this in one query, like:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1>
SELECT ?name ?url
WHERE {
  ?a foaf:name ?name
  FILTER regex(?name,'(prepare|for|aricent)')
  ?a foaf:url ?url
}
```

Which will return any string that contains any of those words.

Alternatively if you only want strings that have all those words you could do

```
  FILTER regex(?name,'prepare')
  FILTER regex(?name,'for')
  FILTER regex(?name,'aricent')
```

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: sir if we know the exact word/exact number of words,we can use this format.But the user can even enter as " how can i prepare for placements in aricent" and the next time " preparing for interview for aricent" ,etc. In that case i must take each word and use it here to DYNAMICALLY create a query each time without altering it each time.So only i used an array to collect all words and execute the query.ELIMATION HERE I MEAN " I MUST GET ONLY THE 3RD TABLE "(above) and 1st and 2nd should not be visible to the user as it has no values.like wise,DISPLAYING ONLY THE TABLE THAT HAS VALUES"  Thank You

Comment: Why would you need to create a new query each time without altering it? Just generate the filter condition on user input, paste it into your query, and execute. Simple. Alternatively, if your actual question is how to check that a query result is empty in Jena, you can simply use `ResultSet.hasNext()` to check if the query has any results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response sir.I got the o/p as i wanted by using resultset.hasnext().Thanks a lot..!!